# Core Data 1-to-many relationship: List all related objects as section header in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uikit

I struggle with Core Data on the iPhone about the following:
I have a 1-to-many relationship in Core Data. Assume the entities are called recipe and category. A category can have many recipes.
I accomplished to get all recipes listed in a UITableView with section headers named after the category.
What i want to achieve is to list all categories as section header, even those which have no recipe:

```
category1   <--- this one should be displayed too
category2
     recipe_x
     recipe_y
category3
     recipe_z
```

---

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category.categoryName" ascending:YES];
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"recipeName" ascending:YES];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1,sortDescriptor2, nil];

 [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"category.categoryName" cacheName:@"Recipes"];
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve this with core data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sections are not really meant to be shown if there are no rows in them.  That is the way the `UITableView` is designed.  If you **really** wanted to force it you would need to add logic to your datasource call of `-numberOfRowsForSection:` to make it appear that there is always one row and then you could play with the `-heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to try and hide the row.

Having said that, it is a **terrible** idea.  Let the sections hide themselves like they were designed to.

Comment: The UI conventions exist for making interface behavior consistent between applications. Overriding this makes your application behave differently from other applications and can cause confusion about the data being presented. I would avoid modifying section behavior, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that cleanly with the sectionNameKeyPath code.   I would modify the fetch request query the categories, and tell it to include sub entitites:

```
[fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];
```

This way it will be efficient in the query, and not faulting everywhere.  From there fleshing out your delegate should be pretty simple.